# Why getElementsByClassName does not work?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to detect screen resolution then set position (like top,left) for multiple screen resolution,but it's not working.
Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

CSS:

```
.Scrolloutside
{
  position:relative;
  left: 550px;
 }
```

javascript:

```
  var nHeight = screen.height;
  var nWidth = screen.width; 
  if (nHeight ==714 && nWidth==1005)
 {
   //document.write("height:"+nHeight+" ,width="+nWidth+"<br>");
   var newsTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('Scrolloutside');
   newsTarget.style.top= "500px";
  }
```

html:

```
<div class = "Scrolloutside">
    <div class="scroller_title">News</div>
<div class="scroller_container">
    <div class="jscroller2_up">
    <?
    echo $secnews;
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working yeah? Are you sure it does nothing? It may do **something** you simply hasn't noticed.

Comment: I have no idea why you all put this on hold.  The line of code `newsTarget.style.top= "500px";` is clearly wrong land that's what the answers explain.  It likely generates a reference error.  This is not a simple typographical error.  This is a programming error that needs explaining as the helpful answers attempt to do.  Voting to reopen.  I see no reason why this question should be on hold.  A simple examination of the small amount of code spots the programming error.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree with you, and have re-opened. I suppose people just figured that mistake was basically a typo, rather than something a little bit more involved.

Answer (score 5):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a `nodeList` or `HTMLCollection` which are both a list of elements, not a single element.  Even if there is only one matching element, it still returns a list with just one item in it.  As such, you have to either get the first item in the list or iterate through the whole list (depending upon what your code wants).

Get the first item from the list (if you can assume there's only one item with the class name):

```
var newsTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('Scrolloutside');
newsTarget[0].style.top= "500px";
```

or iterate through the list (if there may be more than one item with that class name):

```
var newsTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('Scrolloutside');
for (var i = 0; i < newsTarget.length; i++) {
    newsTarget[i].style.top= "500px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
newsTarget[0].style.top= "500px";
```

The`getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0

Answer (score 0):

Use this at the bottom of your page.

```
newsTarget[0].style.top= "500px";
```